# Can Lorentz forces partially cancel centrifugal forces?

Tags: design-alternative, electromagnetism

If we had a  tidally stabilised skyhook (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_tether#/media/File:Skyhooks.gif) with electric charge and with a vector of force aiming towards the center of the Earth, would it cancel part of the centrifugal force that has an opposite vector at (hypothetical) speeds close to escape velocity?

If not, why not?

Comment: If there was a tether attached to a spinning object, the forces are already cancelled out. The tension force is $x$ Newtons. And the Earth is "holding" or "pulling" the tether in also at $x$ Newtons. This is Newton's Third Law.

Comment: @StarMan Thanks for your answer. Would the lorentz force partially or totally cancel the centrifugal if the tether isn't spinning?: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_tether#/media/File:Skyhooks.gif

Comment: If the tether isn't spinning, then there would be no centrifugal force. Centrifugal force isn't technically a force. It's simply an object being prevented by something like a tether from going off in a straight path from its inertia (Newton's First Law).

Comment: @StarMan Thanks for your answer. I was thinking  more in the case that the thether stars orbiting really fast to the point of getting close to escape velocity (just a hypothetical scenario). In that case, I assume there would be some centrifugal force? If yes, would an opposite Lorentz force partially cancel it?

Comment: Welcome to *Space!*  Are you trying to display an image with the link in the question?

Comment: @Albert Initially, I thought this question was referring to a space tether attached to the Earth's surface (like a space elevator). I've never heard of a skyhook before (it's pretty cool!). Correct me if I'm wrong, but your question is this?: If there was an electrically conductive space tether in LEO rotating with two masses, could the Lorentz force decrease the tension in the tether?

Comment: @StarMan Thanks for your answer. My question is indeed very hypothetical. If we have a charged skyhook orbiting the Earth (but not spining), could the centrifugal force be reduced by an opposite lorentz force?